Update the Chinese.SE Twitter icon from “Cn” to 漢?
The Chinese.SE Twitter account still uses the old icon.  Screenshot:



Perhaps we can get this updated to 漢.

That's a point.
Let me try and get the ball rolling.
I've reached out to a Stack Exchange Community Manager, hopefully this will speed things along.
